# Javascript to increase/decrease font size (external css)

Tags: javascript, css, font-size

I managed to pull together a script that will increase the font sizes of parts of a web page using buttons or links. It works in Moz/Chrome, but sticks on IE, tho theoretically it shouldn't have a issue in these major browsers. But I'm stuck on whether or not it's possible to use currentStyle to get the fontSize from a variable populated by getElementsByName; certainly IE is drawing blanks.

Here's my script:

```
function changeFontSize(element,step)
{
    var styleProp = 'font-size';
    step = parseInt(step,10);

    var x = document.getElementsByName(element);

    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++) {

        if (x[i].currentStyle)  {
            var y = parseInt(x[i].currentStyle[styleProp],10);

        } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {           
            var y = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x[i],null).getPropertyValue(styleProp),10);

        }

        x[i].style.fontSize = (y+step) + 'px';
    }
}
```

The 3 sites I've used to pull this together are:

[www.vijayjoshi.org](http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2009/04/02/changing-font-size-on-a-page-with-javascript-for-better-user-experience/)

[www.quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)

and (this isn't spam, this is actually important) //http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/controlling-font-size-with-javascript/

Can anyone point out a solution please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

what about updating your code with the following :

```
function changeFontSize(element,step)
{
 function computeFontSizeUpdate(oE)
 {
 //- init fSize with proper null value
 var fSize = null;
 //- retrieve fSize from style
 if (oE.currentStyle)  {
     fSize = parseInt(oE.currentStyle[styleProp], 10);
 } 
 else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
     var s = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oE,null);
     fSize = (s) ? parseInt(s.getPropertyValue(styleProp),10) : NaN;
 }

 //- check fSize value based on return of parseInt function
 if( isNaN(fSize) == false && fSize != null)
 {
    fSize += nStep + 'px';
    if(oE.currentStyle)
      oE.currentStyle.fontSize = fSize;
    else
      oE.style.fontSize = fSize;
 }
 };

 var styleProp = 'font-size';
 var nStep = parseInt(step, 10);

 //- ensure step value
 if( isNaN(nStep) ) nStep = 0;

 //- get target elements
 var oElems = document.getElementsByName(element);

 if ( oElems && oElems.length == 0)
 {
   var oE = document.getElementById(element);
   if(oE) computeFontSizeUpdate(oE);
 }
 else
 {
   for(oE in oElems) 
   {
    computeFontSizeUpdate(oE);
   }
 }

}
```

I have updated script with fix and few better naming for some variables.

Also, I am sorry cause I am on Mac right now, I wasn't able to test the provided script in IE ... but from what I remember it should do the trick.

Using some JS console you can directly execute directly on this page

```
changeFontSize("nav-tags", 50);
```

and you will notice that the Tags element in the menu bar would get affected :)

Hope this helps

Comment: There's an error here:
`var s = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x[i],null);`
Problem with the x[i] var? Can't see what it should be tho. I tried oE, error message said "No such interface supported".

Comment: Same problem I think. Here's the error I'm getting in Firebug: 'uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMViewCSS.getComputedStyle]"' I think it's on line 12 of your code.

Comment: @Simon : is your issue got fixed ?!